# Plot Tweets Length is not clear why the length has high values

Tags: python, plot, text, nlp

I would like a clarification, because I was wondering why the tweet length arrives until 800 when the tweet text  can be or can have until 280 (less or more) characters?
Doing this script I have this panel. Maybe I am wrong something. Maybe I have also the space counting within len?

```
# Exploring the text lengths
lunghezza =  df['text'].astype(str).apply(len)
lunghezza
0        122
1         97
2         90
3        140
4        123
        ... 
13344    103
13345    160
13346    326
13347    149
13348    205
Name: text, Length: 13349, dtype: int64
# visualize the text length
plt.figure(figsize=(50,44))
plt.xticks(fontsize=80)
plt.yticks(fontsize=80)  
plt.hist(lunghezza, edgecolor = "black", color='darkturquoise');
plt.grid(True, color='gray', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=0.5, axis='y')
# Define x-axis label
plt.xlabel("Length Tweets", fontsize=80)

# Define y-label
plt.ylabel("Number Tweets",fontsize=80)
plt.suptitle('Visualize the text length', fontsize=90)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Hard for us to say exactly because we cannot see your data. But what do you see when you do:

```
df['text'].astype(str).apply(len).sort_values().head(10)
```

This should give you those Tweets with the longest length. Inspect what happens and how the data looks.

Comment: I applied your script and I have this result in two columns: `7648      6; 10550     6; 4724      9; 5120      9; 3501      9; 446      10; 3120     11; 4469     12; 3561     12; 6085     12`...Anyway I added in my question the output of lunghezza.

Comment: @RacheleFranceschini if you just look at your data, what do you see? If you look at only those rows where you have a lot of text, what do you see?

Comment: If I understood your question, I am seeing: words, hashtags, links, special characters, space, italian stop words, https etc.

Comment: @RacheleFranceschini just look at your raw data, inspect it, see what's there and what outliers (in terms of length) it has. That should solve your question.